# Find complex number(s) $z$ for which $|z|$ has maximum and minimum value if $|z-2+2i|=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Find  complex number(s) $z$ for which $|z|$ has maximum and  minimum  value if $|z-2+2i|=1$

My try: I know that $|z-2+2i|=1$ is a circle centered at $(2,-2)$
and having unit radius. Also $|z|$ is the modulus of moving point on this circle and I have to maximize and then minimize $|z|$

By using $$|z+w|>=||z|-|w||$$ I managed to get maximum and minimum values of $|z|$ and they turned out to be $2√2+1$ and $2√2-1$ respectively. But I am not able to get $z$.

I hope somebody will help me and nobody would down vote me If i sound so ignorant because I am at verge of loosing the right of asking a question in this site.

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml

Comment: Did you draw a figure of your circle and the axes of coordinates? If you had, the affixes $z$ of the points where $|z|$ is extremal would become obvious...

Comment: Yes I did, it is a circle in 4th quadrant. But I got no idea how to find the points

Comment: which $|z|$ has maximum and  minimum on circle

Comment: @MyGlasses I did not get you sir

Comment: @RayeesAhmad What $|z|$ means.

Comment: Modulus of z, the distance of moving point from origin...am i right sir.

Comment: Yea. Well can you show circle $|z-2+2i|=1$ in the plane? It's center is $2-2i$ and radius $1$.

Comment: I fail to realise what you intend sir.

Comment: Sorry. Forget that.

Comment: It seems you do not understand your assignment, which in turn inflicts confusion on your Readers.  I suspect that the problem was this: find the complex numbers $z$ on the circle $|z - 2 + 2i| = 1$ which have (a) the maximum value of $|z|$ and (b) the minimum value of $|z|$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

From a geometric point of view, the values of $z$ will be the affixes of the intersections of the circle with the line joining the origin to the centre of the circle.

It will simpler to calculate with the exponential form of complex numbers: $$2-2i=\sqrt2\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{i\pi}4},\enspace\text{hence }\quad z=\dotsm$$

Answer (score 0):

Locus of z:
$$(x-2)^2+(y+2)^=1$$
$|z|$ will be minimum at the point P where
$y=-x$ intersects the circle.
To find the coordinates of P:
$(x-2)^2+(-x+2)^2=1$
 $x²-4x+4+x²-4x+4=1$
 $2x²-8x+7=0$
Applying SriDharacharya formula
$x=2±(1/√2)$
As we have to find minimum of |z|,
therefore
$x=2-(1/√2)$
As $y=-x$
therefore
$y=-2+(1/√2)$
$P(x,y)=P( 2-(1/√2),-2+(1/√2) )$
Minimum value of $|z| = √(x²+y²)
= √(9-4√2)$

Answer (score -2):

Put $z = x+ iy$ .

The equation will become
$| (x-2) + i (y+2) | = 1 $

You will get a circle with equation
$(x-2)^2 + (y+2)^2 = 1$

Parametric points of circle will be
$x= 2 \pm \cos p$
$y= -2 \pm \sin p$

Use [differentiation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/maxima-minima.html) to get maximum and minimum values of $|z|$.

Comment: How do you use differentiation to get the maximum and minimum values for $|z|$?